# How to set label value when databinding asp.net chart control

Tags: asp.net, charts

I am binding a datatable to an asp.net chart but want to set the value of the label to a different dataitem (called ResLabelText) than used for the x or y axis. Can this be done? My databinding code is as follows:

```
  chartRes.Series("Month").XValueMember = "MonthName"
    chartRes.Series("Month").YValueMembers = "Res"
    chartRes.Series("Month").Label = "ResLabelText"
    chartRes.Series("Month").ToolTip = "#VALX"
    chartRes.DataSource = dt
    chartRes.DataBind()
```

Comment: Is this code not working for you for some reason?  What's going wrong right now?

Comment: Correct way is to loop through datatable- see answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way:

```
For Each row In dt.Rows
        Dim point = New DataPoint()
        point.SetValueXY(row.Item("MonthName"), row.Item("Res"))
        point.Label = row.Item("LabelRes")
        point.ToolTip = row.Item("MonthName")
        chartRes.Series("Month").Points.Add(point)
    Next
```